# Swagger UI for Typescript Express project without class based controllers

Tags: typescript, express, types, swagger

I have added types to an existing express js project.
The codebase uses functional programming rather than class based.

All the integrations tutorials use class based modules to make use of types and create Swagger json.
Is there a way to not shift to Class based modules and still have swagger working with types in an existing project?